# why declaring a button on the Start() method makes the scene colorless?

Tags: java, javafx

why declaring a button on the Start() method makes the scene colorless?

in my code,
if i comment the button declaretion,it simply shows the color of the scene.

but if i put the declaretion ,the color doesn't show.

why is that?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class scene1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button button=new Button("problem");
        Pane pane1=new Pane();
        pane1.setPrefSize(600, 600);
        Scene sceneNew=new Scene(pane1, Color.AQUAMARINE);
        primaryStage.setScene(sceneNew);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your button variable isn't used anywhere so commenting it won't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either [VBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html) or [HBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) class.

Here is a example with VBox.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class scene1 extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button button=new Button("problem");
        Pane pane1=new Pane();
        pane1.setPrefSize(600, 600);
        VBox vbox = new VBox(50);

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(button, pane1);

        //mainScene = new Scene(box, 200, 200);
        Scene sceneNew=new Scene(vbox, 200, 200, Color.AQUAMARINE);
        primaryStage.setScene(sceneNew);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Button");
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: the button is never added to the scene in the question